# Find all possible a and b for which α is nonempty

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $a$ and $b$ be two integers. The relation  $\alpha\subseteq \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ is defined by $x \alpha y$ if and only if $аx+by=1$.

Find all possible $a$ and $b$ for which $α$ is nonempty.

For all  $а$ and $b$ proof existence or absence of each of following properties: irreflexive, symmetric, antysymmetric and transitive.

Here is my attempt [[link]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rXLm.jpg)

Comment: Do you know Bezouts identity? It shows directly that $(a,b)\in\alpha$ if and only if $\operatorname{gcd}(a,b)=1$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know that identity

Comment: @FateMetric: [Bezout’s identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout's_identity).